# How to mimic copy-namespaces="no" in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to rewrite this xslt piece in XSLT 1.0, which does not support "copy-namespaces".

```
<xsl:copy-of copy-namespaces="no" select="maml:alertSet/maml:alert" />
```

How?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following mimics the XSLT 2.0 construct:

Create templates in a mode that will re-construct your nodes without namespaces:

```
<!-- generate a new element in the same namespace as the matched element,
     copying its attributes, but without copying its unused namespace nodes,
     then continue processing content in the "copy-no-namepaces" mode -->

<xsl:template match="*" mode="copy-no-namespaces">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comment()| processing-instruction()" mode="copy-no-namespaces">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```

Apply-templates for the desired element(s) in that mode:

```
<xsl:apply-templates  select="maml:alertSet/maml:alert" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
```

Comment: Your recursive template doesn't work correctly for attributes. As it is now it copies the attribute into the containing element, but also it copies the value of the attribute as text. You need to change `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>` (drop the `@*`)