# XSL Copy nodes without xmlns

Tags: xslt, copy, xml-namespaces

I have a specific problem. I have to transform an XML structure to other, where the base XSD is same, different only the namespace definition. The first part is simple, because here I have to use field-mapping. The second part is the simple copy. And here is the problem. The copied "main" node contains the original xmlns attribute. I need to remove this "attribute".

The base xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S2SCTIcf:SCTIcfBlkCredTrf xmlns:S2SCTIcf="urn:S2SCTIcf:xsd:$SCTIcfBlkCredTrf"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:S2SCTIcf:xsd:$SCTIcfBlkCredTrf SCTIcfBlkCredTrf.xsd">
    <S2SCTIcf:SndgInst>XXXXXXX0</S2SCTIcf:SndgInst>
    <S2SCTIcf:RcvgInst>YYYYYYY0</S2SCTIcf:RcvgInst>
    <S2SCTIcf:FileRef>2013111200800546</S2SCTIcf:FileRef>
    <S2SCTIcf:SrvcId>SCT</S2SCTIcf:SrvcId>
    <S2SCTIcf:TstCode>T</S2SCTIcf:TstCode>
    <S2SCTIcf:FType>ICF</S2SCTIcf:FType>
    <S2SCTIcf:FDtTm>2013-11-12T16:26:31</S2SCTIcf:FDtTm>
    <S2SCTIcf:NumCTBlk>1</S2SCTIcf:NumCTBlk>
    <S2SCTIcf:NumPCRBlk>0</S2SCTIcf:NumPCRBlk>
    <S2SCTIcf:NumRFRBlk>0</S2SCTIcf:NumRFRBlk>
    <S2SCTIcf:NumROIBlk>0</S2SCTIcf:NumROIBlk>
    <S2SCTIcf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.02">
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>xxddccxxaaa</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>2013-11-12T16:26:31</CreDtTm>
            <NbOfTxs>1</NbOfTxs>
            <TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="EUR">469.12</TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt>
            <IntrBkSttlmDt>2013-11-13</IntrBkSttlmDt>
            <SttlmInf>
                <SttlmMtd>CLRG</SttlmMtd>
                <ClrSys>
                    <Prtry>ST2</Prtry>
                </ClrSys>
            </SttlmInf>
            <InstgAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <BIC>XXXXXXX0</BIC>
                </FinInstnId>
            </InstgAgt>
        </GrpHdr>
        <CdtTrfTxInf>
            <PmtId>
                <EndToEndId>1114405599,1114382976</EndToEndId>
                <TxId>F3232323232</TxId>
            </PmtId>
            <PmtTpInf>
                <SvcLvl>
                    <Cd>SEPA</Cd>
                </SvcLvl>
            </PmtTpInf>
            <IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="EUR">469.12</IntrBkSttlmAmt>
            <ChrgBr>SLEV</ChrgBr>
            <Dbtr>
                <Nm>ddffrrddsaasas</Nm>
                <PstlAdr>
                    <Ctry>HU</Ctry>
                    <AdrLine>dssdsdsdsdsdaas</AdrLine>
                </PstlAdr>
            </Dbtr>
            <DbtrAcct>
                <Id>
                    <IBAN>HU26XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</IBAN>
                </Id>
            </DbtrAcct>
            <DbtrAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <BIC>CCCCHUH0</BIC>
                </FinInstnId>
            </DbtrAgt>
            <CdtrAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <BIC>CVCVCVCVCVC</BIC>
                </FinInstnId>
            </CdtrAgt>
            <Cdtr>
                <Nm>XXXXX</Nm>
                <PstlAdr>
                    <Ctry>DE</Ctry>
                </PstlAdr>
            </Cdtr>
            <CdtrAcct>
                <Id>
                    <IBAN>DE12vvvvvvvhghhg</IBAN>
                </Id>
            </CdtrAcct>
            <RmtInf>
                <Ustrd>0000000000,0000000000 </Ustrd>
            </RmtInf>
        </CdtTrfTxInf>
    </S2SCTIcf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf>
</S2SCTIcf:SCTIcfBlkCredTrf>
```

The xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns0="urn:S2SCTIcf:xsd:$SCTIcfBlkCredTrf"
    xmlns:sw8="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.02"
    xmlns:S2SCTScf="urn:S2SCTScf:xsd:$SCTScfBlkCredTrf" exclude-result-prefixes="xs ns0 ">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="var1_SCTIcfBlkCredTrf" select="ns0:SCTIcfBlkCredTrf"/>
        <S2SCTScf:SCTScfBlkCredTrf
            xsi:schemaLocation="urn:S2SCTScf:xsd:$SCTScfBlkCredTrf SCTScfBlkCredTrf.xsd"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:S2SCTScf="urn:S2SCTScf:xsd:$SCTScfBlkCredTrf">
            <xsl:for-each select="$var1_SCTIcfBlkCredTrf">
                <S2SCTScf:SndgInst>
                    <xsl:value-of select="string(ns0:RcvgInst)"/>
                </S2SCTScf:SndgInst>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="$var1_SCTIcfBlkCredTrf">
                <S2SCTScf:RcvgInst>
                    <xsl:value-of select="string(ns0:SndgInst)"/>
                </S2SCTScf:RcvgInst>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="$var1_SCTIcfBlkCredTrf">
                <S2SCTScf:SrvcId>
                    <xsl:value-of select="string(ns0:SrvcId)"/>
                </S2SCTScf:SrvcId>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="$var1_SCTIcfBlkCredTrf">
                <S2SCTScf:TstCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="string(ns0:TstCode)"/>
                </S2SCTScf:TstCode>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <S2SCTScf:FType>SCF</S2SCTScf:FType>
            <xsl:for-each select="$var1_SCTIcfBlkCredTrf">
                <S2SCTScf:FileRef>
                    <xsl:value-of select="string(ns0:FileRef)"/>
                </S2SCTScf:FileRef>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <S2SCTScf:RoutingInd>DIR</S2SCTScf:RoutingInd>
            <xsl:for-each select="$var1_SCTIcfBlkCredTrf">
                <S2SCTScf:FileBusDt>
                    <xsl:value-of select="string(ns0:FDtTm)"/>
                </S2SCTScf:FileBusDt>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <S2SCTScf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.02">
                <xsl:for-each select="$var1_SCTIcfBlkCredTrf/ns0:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf">
                    <GrpHdr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$var1_SCTIcfBlkCredTrf/ns0:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf">
                            <MsgId>
                                <xsl:value-of select="string(sw8:GrpHdr/sw8:MsgId)"/>
                            </MsgId>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$var1_SCTIcfBlkCredTrf/ns0:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf">
                            <CreDtTm>
                                <xsl:value-of select="string(sw8:GrpHdr/sw8:CreDtTm)"/>
                            </CreDtTm>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$var1_SCTIcfBlkCredTrf/ns0:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf">
                            <NbOfTxs>
                                <xsl:value-of select="string(sw8:GrpHdr/sw8:NbOfTxs)"/>
                            </NbOfTxs>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$var1_SCTIcfBlkCredTrf/ns0:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf">
                            <xsl:variable name="var2_TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt"
                                select="sw8:GrpHdr/sw8:TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt"/>
                            <TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt>
                                <xsl:attribute name="Ccy" namespace="">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="string($var2_TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt/@Ccy)"/>
                                </xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:value-of
                                    select="string(number(string($var2_TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt)))"/>
                            </TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$var1_SCTIcfBlkCredTrf/ns0:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf">
                            <IntrBkSttlmDt>
                                <xsl:value-of select="string(sw8:GrpHdr/sw8:IntrBkSttlmDt)"/>
                            </IntrBkSttlmDt>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <SttlmInf>
                            <xsl:for-each select="$var1_SCTIcfBlkCredTrf/ns0:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf">
                                <SttlmMtd>
                                    <xsl:value-of
                                        select="string(sw8:GrpHdr/sw8:SttlmInf/sw8:SttlmMtd)"/>
                                </SttlmMtd>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                            <ClrSys>
                                <xsl:for-each select="$var1_SCTIcfBlkCredTrf/ns0:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf">
                                    <Prtry>
                                        <xsl:value-of
                                            select="string(sw8:GrpHdr/sw8:SttlmInf/sw8:ClrSys/sw8:Prtry)"
                                        />
                                    </Prtry>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </ClrSys>
                        </SttlmInf>
                        <InstdAgt>
                            <FinInstnId>
                                <xsl:for-each
                                    select="$var1_SCTIcfBlkCredTrf/ns0:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf/sw8:GrpHdr/sw8:InstgAgt">
                                    <BIC>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="string(sw8:FinInstnId/sw8:BIC)"/>
                                    </BIC>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </FinInstnId>
                        </InstdAgt>
                    </GrpHdr>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$var1_SCTIcfBlkCredTrf/ns0:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf/sw8:CdtTrfTxInf" />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </S2SCTScf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf>
        </S2SCTScf:SCTScfBlkCredTrf>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The wrong part of output:

```
...
     </InstdAgt>
  </GrpHdr>
  <CdtTrfTxInf xmlns:S2SCTIcf="urn:S2SCTIcf:xsd:$SCTIcfBlkCredTrf">
     <PmtId>
        <EndToEndId>1114405599,1114382976</EndToEndId>
        <TxId>F3232323232</TxId>
 ...
```

I don't want to get the *xmlns:S2SCTIcf="urn:S2SCTIcf:xsd:$SCTIcfBlkCredTrf"* attribute this line.

Have someone any idea?

Thank you!

Feri

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your issue is that

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$var1_SCTIcfBlkCredTrf/ns0:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf/sw8:CdtTrfTxInf" />
```

copies the node from the original tree *including* its "namespace nodes", i.e. the namespace declarations that were in scope at that point in the original document.  When this node is serialized any of these namespace nodes that are not already in force at this point in the output document will be declared by the serializer.

If you were able to use XSLT 2.0 then you could try setting [`copy-namespaces="no"` on the `copy-of`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#copy-of) but that isn't an option in XSLT 1.0.  So instead of using `copy-of` you need to use templates to copy that node (and all its descendants recursively) *without* including the namespace nodes.  The simplest way I can think of to do this is to declare two additional templates

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="copy">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="copy" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()" mode="copy">
  <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```

and then replace that `copy-of` with

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"
   select="$var1_SCTIcfBlkCredTrf/ns0:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf/sw8:CdtTrfTxInf" />
```

The trick here is that `xsl:element` is creating a *new* element node that happens to have the same name and namespace as the original one, rather than copying the original node, so it doesn't copy the namespace nodes.

Comment: Using the `namespace=` in the template causes all of the other namespaces to be added to the elements which doesn't look to be what the OP wanted. That's why I removed it from my answer.

Comment: @MatthewGreen the way I read the question the OP doesn't want to change the namespace of the element being copied, they just want to remove the redundant declaration of a (different) unused prefix.

Comment: That's probably true. I read it that he wanted the current output minus the namespace.

Comment: The reference to copy-namespaces="no" in XSLT 2.0 is incorrect. This option only removes *unused* namespaces, whereas the OP wants to change the namespace of the copied elements.

Comment: @MichaelKay That was how I initially (mis-)read the question too, but given that the `sw8` prefix used in the `copy-of` select expression is the same namespace URI as the `xmlns` on `<S2SCTScf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf>` (the parent under which the `copy-of` result is to be inserted), it appears that they _do_ want to keep the same namespace for the copy and just remove unused prefix mappings.

Comment: @IanRoberts, thanks! While the behavior is not exactly easy to understand, this does exactly what I needed. Nodes copied in this way will have the original namespaces and all their attributes, except for the namespace declarations that would otherwise be included as well.

Answer (score 14):

You can use a [variant of the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030832/1078110) to get what you want.

Basically, you would create a template to rebuild that element without any namespaces. So you would add the following two templates to your current XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="copy-no-namespaces">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comment()| processing-instruction()" mode="copy-no-namespaces">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```

And then update your `copy-of` to

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$var1_SCTIcfBlkCredTrf/ns0:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf/sw8:CdtTrfTxInf" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
```