# XSL 1.0 group by and sum SalesAmount and related / joined Tax records

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have an invoice xml where I need to perform a grouping / sum on itemid's 
For instance for ItemId 444 I need a lineamount of 100 + 25 = 125 and ItemId 555 = 200 + 15. Lot's of examples out there how to do this you're about to say but I have another requirement. I also need to do the same grouping and sum for my TaxTrans\TaxAmounts and TaxTrans\TaxBaseAmounts based on the joining InventTransId field (AABB / BBCC) between CustInvoiceTrans and TaxTrans.

Before:

```
  <CustInvoiceJour class="entity">
          <CustInvoiceTrans class="entity">
            <InventTransId>AABB</InventTransId>
            <InvoiceId>SI100</InvoiceId>
            <ItemId>444</ItemId>
            <LineAmount>100</LineAmount>
          </CustInvoiceTrans>
          <CustInvoiceTrans class="entity">
            <InventTransId>BBCC</InventTransId>
            <InvoiceId>SI100</InvoiceId>
            <ItemId>444</ItemId>
            <LineAmount>25</LineAmount>
          </CustInvoiceTrans>
          <CustInvoiceTrans class="entity">
            <InventTransId>CCDD</InventTransId>
            <InvoiceId>SI100</InvoiceId>
            <ItemId>555</ItemId>
            <LineAmount>200</LineAmount>
          </CustInvoiceTrans>
          <CustInvoiceTrans class="entity">
            <InventTransId>DDEE</InventTransId>
            <InvoiceId>SI100</InvoiceId>
            <ItemId>555</ItemId>
            <LineAmount>15</LineAmount>
          </CustInvoiceTrans>         
          <CustInvoiceTrans class="entity">
            <InventTransId>EEFF</InventTransId>
            <InvoiceId>SI100</InvoiceId>
            <ItemId>12345</ItemId>
            <LineAmount>40</LineAmount>
          </CustInvoiceTrans>
          <TaxTrans class="entity">
            <InventTransId>AABB</InventTransId>
            <TaxAmount>-21</TaxAmount>
            <TaxBaseAmount>-100</TaxBaseAmount>
            <TaxValue>21.00</TaxValue>
          </TaxTrans>
          <TaxTrans class="entity">
            <InventTransId>BBCC</InventTransId>
            <TaxAmount>-5.25</TaxAmount>
            <TaxBaseAmount>-25</TaxBaseAmount>
            <TaxValue>21.00</TaxValue>
          </TaxTrans>
          <TaxTrans class="entity">
            <InventTransId>CCDD</InventTransId>
            <TaxAmount>-42</TaxAmount>
            <TaxBaseAmount>-200</TaxBaseAmount>
            <TaxValue>21.00</TaxValue>
          </TaxTrans>
          <TaxTrans class="entity">
            <InventTransId>DDEE</InventTransId>
            <TaxAmount>-3.15</TaxAmount>
            <TaxBaseAmount>-15</TaxBaseAmount>
            <TaxValue>15</TaxValue>
          </TaxTrans>
          <TaxTrans class="entity">
            <InventTransId>EEFF</InventTransId>
            <TaxAmount>-8.40</TaxAmount>
            <TaxBaseAmount>-40</TaxBaseAmount>
            <TaxValue>15</TaxValue>
          </TaxTrans>         
</CustInvoiceJour>
```

Required output:

```
<CustInvoiceJour class="entity">
    <CustInvoiceTrans class="entity">
        <InventTransId>AABB</InventTransId>
        <InvoiceId>SI100</InvoiceId>
        <ItemId>444</ItemId>
        <LineAmount>125</LineAmount>
    </CustInvoiceTrans>
    <CustInvoiceTrans class="entity">
        <InventTransId>CCDD</InventTransId>
        <InvoiceId>SI100</InvoiceId>
        <ItemId>555</ItemId>
        <LineAmount>215</LineAmount>
    </CustInvoiceTrans>
    <CustInvoiceTrans class="entity">
        <InventTransId>EEFF</InventTransId>
        <InvoiceId>SI100</InvoiceId>
        <ItemId>12345</ItemId>
        <LineAmount>40</LineAmount>
    </CustInvoiceTrans>
    <TaxTrans class="entity">
        <InventTransId>AABB</InventTransId>
        <TaxAmount>-26.25</TaxAmount>
        <TaxBaseAmount>-125</TaxBaseAmount>
        <TaxValue>21.00</TaxValue>
    </TaxTrans>
    <TaxTrans class="entity">
        <InventTransId>CCDD</InventTransId>
        <TaxAmount>-45.15</TaxAmount>
        <TaxBaseAmount>-215</TaxBaseAmount>
        <TaxValue>21.00</TaxValue>
    </TaxTrans>
    <TaxTrans class="entity">
        <InventTransId>EEFF</InventTransId>
        <TaxAmount>-8.40</TaxAmount>
        <TaxBaseAmount>-40</TaxBaseAmount>
        <TaxValue>15</TaxValue>
    </TaxTrans>       
</CustInvoiceJour>
```

I don't know if this is even possible. Let alone where to start?

Mike

Comment: As you say you know how to group and sum you should simply apply that concept twice, once for the `CustInvoiceTrans` elements and once for the `TaxTrans` elements. They seem to occur in the same document but you seem to want to group them separately so simply use Muenchian grouping twice, separately for the different elements.

Comment: Thnx Martin but I don't know how to apply group and sum to the (joined) TaxTrans, each have 'unique' InventTransIds?

Comment: Didn't notice that, have written an answer that shows the grouping for the `TaxTrans` by grouping the `CustInvoiceTrans` and then referencing the `TaxTrans` with a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the `CustInvoiceTrans` elements twice, once to group and sum up their components, the second time to create the sum of referenced `TaxTrans` elements which you simply find with a key `<xsl:key name="RefTaxTrans" match="TaxTrans" use="InventTransId"/>`; the following shows how to create the grouped `TaxTrans` and computes the sum for the `TaxAmount`, you just need to copy the other elements respectively sum the other element inside that template and the `TaxTrans` result element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="CustInvoiceTrans" match="CustInvoiceTrans" use="ItemId"/>
  <xsl:key name="RefTaxTrans" match="TaxTrans" use="InventTransId"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CustInvoiceJour">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="CustInvoiceTrans[generate-id() = generate-id(key('CustInvoiceTrans', ItemId)[1])]" mode="tax"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CustInvoiceTrans" mode="tax">
      <TaxTrans>
          <xsl:variable name="referenced-tax" select="key('RefTaxTrans', key('CustInvoiceTrans', ItemId)/InventTransId)"/>
          <TaxAmount>
              <xsl:value-of select="sum($referenced-tax/TaxAmount)"/>
          </TaxAmount>
      </TaxTrans>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMG

You can then add the normal grouping for the CustInvoiceTrans elements with another `apply-templates` in the default mode before the `<xsl:apply-templates select="CustInvoiceTrans[generate-id() = generate-id(key('CustInvoiceTrans', ItemId)[1])]" mode="tax"/>` line. Or it might be easier to store the first item of each group and then apply-templates twice, once in the default, unnamed mode, the second time in the mode for the referenced items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="CustInvoiceTrans" match="CustInvoiceTrans" use="ItemId"/>
  <xsl:key name="RefTaxTrans" match="TaxTrans" use="InventTransId"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CustInvoiceJour">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
          <xsl:variable name="group-heads"
             select="CustInvoiceTrans[generate-id() = generate-id(key('CustInvoiceTrans', ItemId)[1])]"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$group-heads"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$group-heads" mode="tax"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CustInvoiceTrans/LineAmount">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('CustInvoiceTrans', ../ItemId)/LineAmount)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CustInvoiceTrans" mode="tax">
      <TaxTrans class="entity">
          <xsl:variable name="referenced-tax" select="key('RefTaxTrans', key('CustInvoiceTrans', ItemId)/InventTransId)"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$referenced-tax[1]/InventTransId"/>
          <TaxAmount>
              <xsl:value-of select="sum($referenced-tax/TaxAmount)"/>
          </TaxAmount>
          <TaxBaseAmount>
              <xsl:value-of select="sum($referenced-tax/TaxBaseAmount)"/>
          </TaxBaseAmount>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$referenced-tax[1]/TaxValue"/>
      </TaxTrans>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMG/1

Comment: You’re the best Martin. Thanks so much! I'm currently trying to implement your answer in my (real live) xml which is more complex regarding namespaces than the example. I hope I can make it work.. Gr. mike

Comment: Looks like I can get it to work. The TaxTrans however gets the original xmlns attribute:
  <TaxTrans class="entity" xmlns="" xmlns:msxsl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesInvoice">

For the values I can use a template (copy no namespace / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998180/xsl-copy-nodes-without-xmlns)

Probably a noob question but can you tell me how to get rid of the namespace declaration?

Comment: There's one important thing I forgot to mention. I want to do this 'special processing' only when the itemid starts with 2907. For all other custinvoicetrans & taxtrans I want to keep them in the output 'as is'. How can I conditionally do the group & sum based on the itemid's first 4 characters?

Comment: If the output elements of the stylesheet that are newly created are meant to be in the namespace of the input document (assuming they are all in the same one) you can replace the `<TraxTrans class="entity">...</TraxTrans>` with e.g. `<xsl:element name="TraxTrans" namespace="{namespace-uri()}"><xsl:attribute name="class">entity></xsl:attribute>...</xsl:element>`.

Comment: I am afraid the reduction on certain elements for the grouping changes the requirement quite a bit, ask a new question on that with the necessary details and samples if you can't adapt the posted solution on your own. It will be important to know for instance whether the `CustInvoiceTrans` that need to be grouped and those that don't need to be grouped are intermingled or not and whether you need to preserve the order, otherwise you might be able to simply add predicates `CustInvoiceTans[starts-with(ItemId, '2907')]` in all the places of the XSLT where the grouping happens.

Comment: Martin, do you have a 'start / link' how something like this could be accomplished in xsl 2.0?

Comment: The link I posted in your new question https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMG/3 was an attempt that does work with XSLT 2, I only I didn't manage to "port" it back to XSLT 1. I have also now simplified it a bit to take advantage of XSLT 2/XPath 2 features: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMG/4 so that is one way in XSLT 2 to preserve the order of elements but group some of them. A different approach, given that you want to group, is obviously `for-each-group`, https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm is a nice book on XSLT 1 and 2 for instance.

Comment: I'm getting an 'Expected Token error' which is (according to you ;) ) caused by a Microsoft xslt processor. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fa61c611-2199-46e6-a555-25ec81c77c99/expected-token-found-existsindexof-15gtlt-40-25-40-10-40?forum=xmlandnetfx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179114/discussion-between-mike-dole-and-martin-honnen).