# Output all elements instead of grouped elements only when conditionally group / sum xml via XSL

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I had a requirement to group by and sum records for both sales value and the joined tax values. Posted on stack:
[XSL 1.0 group by and sum SalesAmount and related / joined Tax records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065428/xsl-1-0-group-by-and-sum-salesamount-and-related-joined-tax-records?noredirect=1#comment91083753_52065428)

Thanks to Martin Honnen I got the right xsl to do that!

Requirement was: on an xml I had 4 invoice lines with the same itemid which I wanted to group and sum the lineamount thus resulting in 1 line with the itemid / total amount. For the Tax records in the same xml, connected by an ID to the invoice records, I wanted the same output.

The thing is that the xsl I’ve created always groups / sums the invoice and tax elements where this is more an exception. For instance when the itemid starts with a specific set of characters (e.g 400 in the example below).

I succeeded in conditionally do the grouping (starts-with(msxsl:ItemId) but I want all other elements in my output ‘as is’ (All CustInvoiceJour elements,  All other CustInvoiceTrans records not grouped, All other TaxTrans records not grouped, MarkupTransHeader, FormLetterRemarks, etc)

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Message">
  <Header>
    <MessageId>{F18CC6D0A389}</MessageId>
    <SourceEndpoint>AAA</SourceEndpoint>
    <DestinationEndpoint>INVOICE</DestinationEndpoint>
    <Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/SalesSalesInvoiceService/read</Action>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <MessageParts xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Message">
      <SalesInvoice xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesInvoice">
        <CustInvoiceJour class="entity">
          <AccountcategoryId>AFAD</AccountcategoryId>
          <CreateDateTime>2018-07-27T16:03:01Z</CreateDateTime>
          <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
          <CustInvoiceTrans class="entity">
            <DlvDate>2018-07-31</DlvDate>
            <ExtGtin>2907557321149</ExtGtin>
            <InventTransId>12515771_067</InventTransId>
            <InvoiceDate>2018-07-27</InvoiceDate>
            <ItemId>400100</ItemId>
            <ItemName>Main Item</ItemName>
            <LineAmount>101.86</LineAmount>
            <LineNum>1.0000000000</LineNum>
            <PriceUnit>1.00</PriceUnit>
            <Qty>1.00</Qty>
          </CustInvoiceTrans>
          <CustInvoiceTrans class="entity">
            <DlvDate>2018-07-31</DlvDate>
            <ExtGtin>2907557321149</ExtGtin>
            <InventTransId>12515772_067</InventTransId>
            <InvoiceDate>2018-07-27</InvoiceDate>
            <ItemId>400201</ItemId>
            <ItemName>Sub Item 1</ItemName>
            <LineAmount>29.50</LineAmount>
            <LineNum>2.0000000000</LineNum>
            <PriceUnit>1.00</PriceUnit>
            <Qty>1.00</Qty>
          </CustInvoiceTrans>
          <CustInvoiceTrans class="entity">
            <DlvDate>2018-07-31</DlvDate>
            <ExtGtin>2907557321149</ExtGtin>
            <InventTransId>12515773_067</InventTransId>
            <InvoiceDate>2018-07-27</InvoiceDate>
            <ItemId>400202</ItemId>
            <ItemName>Sub Item 2</ItemName>
            <LineAmount>31.20</LineAmount>
            <LineNum>3.0000000000</LineNum>
            <PriceUnit>1.00</PriceUnit>
            <Qty>1.00</Qty>
          </CustInvoiceTrans>
          <CustInvoiceTrans class="entity">
            <DlvDate>2018-07-31</DlvDate>
            <ExtGtin>2907557321149</ExtGtin>
            <InventTransId>12523411_067</InventTransId>
            <InvoiceDate>2018-07-27</InvoiceDate>
            <ItemId>400203</ItemId>
            <ItemName>Sub Item 3</ItemName>
        <LineAmount>10.00</LineAmount>
            <LineNum>4.0000000000</LineNum>
            <PriceUnit>1.00</PriceUnit>
            <Qty>1.00</Qty>
          </CustInvoiceTrans>
          <CustInvoiceTrans class="entity">
            <DlvDate>2018-07-31</DlvDate>
            <ExtGtin></ExtGtin>
            <InventTransId>12523412_067</InventTransId>
            <InvoiceDate>2018-07-27</InvoiceDate>
            <ItemId>666777</ItemId>
            <ItemName>Completely different item</ItemName>
        <LineAmount>100.00</LineAmount>
            <LineNum>5.0000000000</LineNum>
            <PriceUnit>1.00</PriceUnit>
            <Qty>1.00</Qty>
          </CustInvoiceTrans>
          <CustInvoiceTrans class="entity">
            <DlvDate>2018-07-31</DlvDate>
            <ExtGtin></ExtGtin>
            <InventTransId>12523413_067</InventTransId>
            <InvoiceDate>2018-07-27</InvoiceDate>
            <ItemId>666778</ItemId>
            <ItemName>Completely different item</ItemName>
        <LineAmount>200.00</LineAmount>
            <LineNum>6.0000000000</LineNum>
            <PriceUnit>1.00</PriceUnit>
            <Qty>1.00</Qty>
          </CustInvoiceTrans>
          <TaxTrans class="entity">
            <TaxAmount>-9.45</TaxAmount>
            <TaxBaseAmount>-45.00</TaxBaseAmount>
            <TaxValue>21.00</TaxValue>
          </TaxTrans>
          <TaxTrans class="entity">
            <InventTransId>12515771_067</InventTransId>
            <TaxAmount>-21.39</TaxAmount>
            <TaxBaseAmount>-101.86</TaxBaseAmount>
            <TaxValue>21.00</TaxValue>
          </TaxTrans>
          <TaxTrans class="entity">
            <InventTransId>12515772_067</InventTransId>
            <TaxAmount>-6.20</TaxAmount>
            <TaxBaseAmount>-29.50</TaxBaseAmount>
            <TaxValue>21.00</TaxValue>
          </TaxTrans>
          <TaxTrans class="entity">
            <InventTransId>12515773_067</InventTransId>
            <TaxAmount>-6.55</TaxAmount>
            <TaxBaseAmount>-31.20</TaxBaseAmount>
            <TaxValue>21.00</TaxValue>
          </TaxTrans>
          <TaxTrans class="entity">
            <InventTransId>12523411_067</InventTransId>
            <TaxAmount>-2.10</TaxAmount>
            <TaxBaseAmount>-10.00</TaxBaseAmount>
            <TaxValue>21.00</TaxValue>
          </TaxTrans>
          <TaxTrans class="entity">
            <InventTransId>12523412_067</InventTransId>
            <TaxAmount>-21.00</TaxAmount>
            <TaxBaseAmount>-100.00</TaxBaseAmount>
            <TaxValue>21.00</TaxValue>
          </TaxTrans>
          <TaxTrans class="entity">
            <InventTransId>12523413_067</InventTransId>
            <TaxAmount>-42.00</TaxAmount>
            <TaxBaseAmount>-200.00</TaxBaseAmount>
            <TaxValue>21.00</TaxValue>
          </TaxTrans>
          <MarkupTransHeader class="entity">
            <CalculatedAmount>45.00</CalculatedAmount>
            <ExemptTax>No</ExemptTax>
            <MarkupCategory>Fixed</MarkupCategory>
            <MarkupCode>HD</MarkupCode>
            <TaxValue>21.00</TaxValue>
          </MarkupTransHeader>
          <FormLetterRemarks class="entity">
            <LanguageId>nl-be</LanguageId>
          </FormLetterRemarks>
          <CompanyInfo class="entity">
            <LanguageId>NL</LanguageId>
          </CompanyInfo>
        </CustInvoiceJour>
      </SalesInvoice>
    </MessageParts>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesInvoice">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <!-- Geen lege regels in xml indien elementen niet worden meegenomen van input naar output-->
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy-no-namespaces">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="comment()| processing-instruction()" mode="copy-no-namespaces">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:key name="CustInvoiceTransKey" match="msxsl:CustInvoiceJour/msxsl:CustInvoiceTrans[starts-with(msxsl:ItemId, '400')]" use="msxsl:ExtGtin"/>
  <xsl:key name="RefTaxTransKey" match="msxsl:CustInvoiceJour/msxsl:TaxTrans" use="msxsl:InventTransId"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="msxsl:CustInvoiceJour">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/> 
      <!---  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /> -->
      <xsl:variable name="group-heads"
            select="msxsl:CustInvoiceTrans[generate-id() = generate-id(key('CustInvoiceTransKey', msxsl:ExtGtin)[1])]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$group-heads"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$group-heads" mode="tax"/>
      <!--- <xsl:value-of select="$group-heads" /> -->
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="msxsl:CustInvoiceTrans/msxsl:LineAmount">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('CustInvoiceTransKey', ../msxsl:ExtGtin)/msxsl:LineAmount)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="msxsl:CustInvoiceJour/msxsl:CustInvoiceTrans" mode="tax">
    <xsl:element name="TraxTrans" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
      <xsl:attribute name="class">entity</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:variable name="referenced-tax" select="key('RefTaxTransKey', key('CustInvoiceTransKey', msxsl:ExtGtin)/msxsl:InventTransId)"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$referenced-tax[1]/msxsl:InventTransId" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
      <xsl:element name="TaxAmount" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="sum($referenced-tax/msxsl:TaxAmount)"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="TaxBaseAmount" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="sum($referenced-tax/msxsl:TaxBaseAmount)"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$referenced-tax[1]/msxsl:TaxValue"  mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Message">
  <Header>
    <MessageId>{F18CC6D0A389}</MessageId>
    <SourceEndpoint>AAA</SourceEndpoint>
    <DestinationEndpoint>INVOICE</DestinationEndpoint>

    <Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/SalesSalesInvoiceService/read</Action>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <MessageParts>
      <SalesInvoice xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesInvoice">
        <CustInvoiceJour class="entity">
          <CustInvoiceTrans class="entity">
            <DlvDate>2018-07-31</DlvDate>
            <ExtGtin>2907557321149</ExtGtin>
            <InventTransId>12515771_067</InventTransId>
            <InvoiceDate>2018-07-27</InvoiceDate>
            <ItemId>400100</ItemId>
            <ItemName>Main Item</ItemName>
            <LineAmount>172.56</LineAmount>
            <LineNum>1.0000000000</LineNum>
            <PriceUnit>1.00</PriceUnit>
            <Qty>1.00</Qty>
          </CustInvoiceTrans>
          <TraxTrans class="entity">
            <InventTransId xmlns="">12515771_067</InventTransId>
            <TaxAmount>-36.24</TaxAmount>
            <TaxBaseAmount>-172.56</TaxBaseAmount>
            <TaxValue xmlns="">21.00</TaxValue>
          </TraxTrans>
        </CustInvoiceJour>
      </SalesInvoice>
    </MessageParts>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Required XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Message">
  <Header>
    <MessageId>{F18CC6D0A389}</MessageId>
    <SourceEndpoint>AAA</SourceEndpoint>
    <DestinationEndpoint>INVOICE</DestinationEndpoint>
    <Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/SalesSalesInvoiceService/read</Action>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <MessageParts>
      <SalesInvoice xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesInvoice">
        <CustInvoiceJour class="entity">
          <AccountcategoryId>AFAD</AccountcategoryId>
          <CreateDateTime>2018-07-27T16:03:01Z</CreateDateTime>
          <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
          <CustInvoiceTrans class="entity">
            <DlvDate>2018-07-31</DlvDate>
            <ExtGtin>2907557321149</ExtGtin>
            <InventTransId>12515771_067</InventTransId>
            <InvoiceDate>2018-07-27</InvoiceDate>
            <ItemId>400100</ItemId>
            <ItemName>Main Item</ItemName>
            <LineAmount>172.56</LineAmount>
            <LineNum>1.0000000000</LineNum>
            <PriceUnit>1.00</PriceUnit>
            <Qty>1.00</Qty>
          </CustInvoiceTrans>
          <CustInvoiceTrans class="entity">
            <DlvDate>2018-07-31</DlvDate>
            <ExtGtin></ExtGtin>
            <InventTransId>12523412_067</InventTransId>
            <InvoiceDate>2018-07-27</InvoiceDate>
            <ItemId>666777</ItemId>
            <ItemName>Completely different item</ItemName>
            <LineAmount>100.00</LineAmount>
            <LineNum>5.0000000000</LineNum>
            <PriceUnit>1.00</PriceUnit>
            <Qty>1.00</Qty>
          </CustInvoiceTrans>
          <CustInvoiceTrans class="entity">
            <DlvDate>2018-07-31</DlvDate>
            <ExtGtin></ExtGtin>
            <InventTransId>12523413_067</InventTransId>
            <InvoiceDate>2018-07-27</InvoiceDate>
            <ItemId>666778</ItemId>
            <ItemName>Completely different item</ItemName>
            <LineAmount>200.00</LineAmount>
            <LineNum>6.0000000000</LineNum>
            <PriceUnit>1.00</PriceUnit>
            <Qty>1.00</Qty>
          </CustInvoiceTrans>
          <TraxTrans class="entity">
            <InventTransId xmlns="">12515771_067</InventTransId>
            <TaxAmount>-36.24</TaxAmount>
            <TaxBaseAmount>-172.56</TaxBaseAmount>
            <TaxValue xmlns="">21.00</TaxValue>
          </TraxTrans>
          <TaxTrans class="entity">
            <InventTransId>12523412_067</InventTransId>
            <TaxAmount>-21.00</TaxAmount>
            <TaxBaseAmount>-100.00</TaxBaseAmount>
            <TaxValue>21.00</TaxValue>
          </TaxTrans>
          <TaxTrans class="entity">
            <InventTransId>12523413_067</InventTransId>
            <TaxAmount>-42.00</TaxAmount>
            <TaxBaseAmount>-200.00</TaxBaseAmount>
            <TaxValue>21.00</TaxValue>
          </TaxTrans>
        </CustInvoiceJour>
      </SalesInvoice>
    </MessageParts>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Small recap: XML with e.g. 10 lines for which I want to conditionally group/sum (sales / tax) 3 lines / elements with identical itemids now only shows the grouped elements where I want to show 8 lines (7 unique + 1 grouped).

I hope I've made myself clear

Comment: There is a lot of data in there, for the child elements of the `CustInvoiceJour` element, do you need to preserve the input order? Or can you live with explicitly processing and grouping and output the items you want to group and outputting the other ones before or after them?

Comment: I think I can live with the other ones after the grouped ones. Retaining the original input order is important when there is no grouping / summing required.

Comment: It is hard doing this with XSLT 1, I have tried to adapt the previous code to include a condition on all the grouping lines (i.e. the match patterns and select expression using Muenchian grouping) and then to elegantly ensure the order is preserved and all elements are processed but the attempt https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMG/2 does not run with an XSLT 1 processor as XSLT 1 doesn't allow the use of one key for the definition of another. So a different approach is needed, I guess you need to hope someone with more XSLT 1 interest than me is willing to help.

Comment: Could be AX 2009 (I use the xsl in AIF) supports xsl 2.0. but then I'd have to make a lot of changes. Thanks Martin for trying! I was so close.