# Add wrapper and change namespace using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML as below.

```
<Document xmlns='urn.system.com' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
        <Row>
            <Field></Field>
        </Row>
    </Document>
```

I want it to output as below.

```
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
   <ns0:Message1>
      <ns1:Document xmlns:ns1="urn.system.com">
         <Row>
            <Field></Field>
         </Row>
      </ns1:Document>
   </ns0:Message1>
</ns0:Messages>
```

I am trying to use the below XSL.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:ns1="urn.system.com" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
    <ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
      <ns0:Message1>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
      </ns0:Message1>
     </ns0:Messages>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It adds the Messages and Message1 but does not add the ns1 with the Document tag.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
   <ns0:Message1>
      <Document xmlns:ns1="urn.system.com">
          <Row>
             <Field></Field>
          </Row>
      </Document>
   </ns0:Message1>
</ns0:Messages>
```

Where am I going wrong? Please help

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact result you want? What you show requires not only renaming the `Document` element; it also means moving all its descendants from the `urn.system.com` namespace to no-namespace.

Comment: Corrected certain copy-paste issues. Basic thing is I need to add the ns0:Messages and ns0:Message1 and also ns1 with Document tag. The other XML tags are not considered for my purpose. Only urn.system.com is considered.

Comment: Have a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998180/xsl-copy-nodes-without-xmlns/20001084