# XMLStarlet + XInclude + XSLT

Tags: xslt, xmlstarlet, xinclude

I'd like to include contents of an XML document into another XML document and transform it via xmlstarlet+XSLT. I'm trying to use XInclude. (A newbie to both XInclude and XSLT, I am.) The xmlstarlet, though, won't process the included XML doc, it just leaves the inclusion node there untouched.

File `a.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<doc xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
a
<xi:include href="b.xml" />
b
</doc>
```

File `b.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<snippet>
c
</snippet>
```

The `x.xsl` "pass-through" template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250" ?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

The command line to be run:

```
xmlstarlet tr x.xsl a.xml
```

And the expected output would be something along the lines of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<doc xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
a
<snippet>
c
</snippet>
b
</doc>
```

Yet, the result I get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
a
<xi:include href="b.xml"/>
b
</doc>
```

Now, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the options listed by `xmlstarlet tr --help`

Comment: I did, and indeed I found the --xinclude parameter. But as I see from M.M.'s answer, I did not use it properly. Why did I write "--xinclude=b.xml" is now beyond my understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As npostavs already suggested, xmlstarlet does not XInclude documents by default, you need to explicitly mention this as `--xinclude`. Then, the result is the one you expected:

```
$ xml tr --xinclude x.xsl a.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
a
<snippet>
c
</snippet>
b
</doc>
```

Except for the `xi:` namespace declaration, which you cannot eliminate with XSLT 1.0 and a simple `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>`. If that's an issue, the stylesheet becomes a little more complicated, since `copy-namespaces="no"` is not available in XSLT 1.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="copy-no-namespaces">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comment()| processing-instruction()" mode="copy-no-namespaces">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the standard approach to mimic `copy-namespaces="no"` in XSLT 1.0, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030832/1987598) by Michael Kay. Then, the result will be

```
$ xml tr --xinclude x.xsl a.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
a
<snippet>
c
</snippet>
b
</doc>
```