# XSLT node copy followed by namespace change

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using XSLT to transform incoming webservice calls from the old to the new version of the XML. In this version change, it means copying an element from a parent to several children in a specific position, plus changing the namespace of the XML, which defines the webservice version.

I'm almost there, but I couldn't make the copied nodes change to the new namespace.

Old XML:

```
<n:request xmlns:n="mynamespace2">
   <n:element>
      <n:id>
         <!-- ... -->
      </n:id>
      <n:source>
         <n:aaa><!-- ... --></n:aaa>
         <n:copyme>
            <n:something attr="value"/>
         </n:copyme>
         <n:bbb><!-- ... --></n:bbb>
         <!-- ... -->
      </n:source>
      <n:ccc/>
      <n:target x="1">
         <n:ddd>text</n:ddd>
         <n:eee>text</n:eee>
         <n:fff><!-- ... --></n:fff>
         <!-- many nodes -->
      </n:target>
      <n:target x="2">
         <n:ddd>text</n:ddd>
         <n:eee>text</n:eee>
         <n:fff><!-- ... --></n:fff>
         <!-- many nodes -->
      </n:target>
   </n:element>
</n:request>
```

I need to copy `copyme` and all its children to each `target` after `eee`, and remove it from the original position.

My XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:myns2="mynamespace2"
        xmlns:myns3="mynamespace3"
        version="1.0">

    <xsl:param name="myns2Param">mynamespace2</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="myns3Param">mynamespace3</xsl:param>

    <!-- identity -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- copy the desired node to each child -->
    <xsl:template match="/myns2:request/myns2:element/myns2:target">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{$myns3Param}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|myns2:ddd|myns2:eee" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="../myns2:source/myns2:copyme" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::myns2:ddd or self::myns2:eee)]" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- remove original node -->
    <xsl:template match="/myns2:request/myns2:element/myns2:source/myns2:copyme" />

    <!-- change namespace -->
    <xsl:template match="@myns2:*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}" namespace="{$myns3Param}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="myns2:*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{$myns3Param}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As it is, this is the output:

```
<request xmlns="mynamespace3">
   <element>
      <id>
         <!-- ... -->
      </id>
      <source>
         <aaa><!-- ... --></aaa>
         <bbb><!-- ... --></bbb>
         <!-- ... -->
      </source>
      <ccc/>
      <target x="1">
         <ddd>text</ddd>
         <eee>text</eee>
         <n:copyme xmlns:n="mynamespace2" xmlns:ns1="mynamespace2">
            <n:something attr="value"/>
         </n:copyme>
         <fff><!-- ... --></fff>
         <!-- many nodes -->
      </target>
      <target x="2">
         <ddd>text</ddd>
         <eee>text</eee>
         <n:copyme xmlns:n="mynamespace2" xmlns:ns1="mynamespace2">
            <n:something attr="value"/>
         </n:copyme>
         <fff><!-- ... --></fff>
         <!-- many nodes -->
      </target>
   </element>
</request>
```

It is almost right, but the original `namespace2` is still there for the copied elements. I looked for a way to fix this, but nothing worked. How can I fix this namespace?

XSLT Implementation: Saxon-HE 9.5.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using XSLT 2.0, you can use `<xsl:copy-of select="..." copy-namespaces="no"/>`

This will get rid of redundant namespaces. If you actually need to move the elements into a different namespace, you can't use `xsl:copy-of` and should perform an explicit recursive descent that copies the elements and attributes but not the namespaces ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030832/455417)).

Comment: In this XSLT I'm with 1.0, no? But anyway, it didn't work, even after changing to `version="2.0"` (I suppose Spring/Java support won't matter to execute it, but I couldn't confirm); the result just remains the same, like it is being ignored.

Comment: You said you were using Saxon-HE 9.5.0.2, which supports XSLT 2.0, so I gave you an answer that uses XSLT 2.0. The only way to achieve this in XSLT 1.0 is to replace your xsl:copy-of with an explicit recursive descent that copies the elements and attributes but not the namespaces. Incidentally the recognition or otherwise of an attribute like copy-namespaces depends on the XSLT processor you are using, not on the value of the version attribute in xsl:stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Anyway, after some reading and retest, `copy-namespaces` is working, but it only removes the unnecessary `ns1` from the copied nodes. I misunderstood its purpose at first, but my issue is not about these "lost" namespace nodes; I have an output with nodes belonging to the old and new namespaces at the same time breaking the schema. Sorry about it.

Comment: [This old post of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9030832/455417) shows the recursive approach, which works for my case (after replacing `namespace-uri()` with my new namespace, otherwise it creates an unbound `n:` namespace, not sure why). I guess this is the correct way to do what I need, after all (the 1.0 way, maybe 2.0 as well). Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, if it breaks the schema that means you don't just want to get rid of redundant namespaces, you actually need to move the elements into a different namespace, which means you can't use xsl:copy-of.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot, that solves the issue. I just edited your answer including all of the relevant comment parts, making it more complete. Hope you don't mind =)