# compare 2 XML and make a sorted one

Tags: xslt

I have a requirement to create a final XML by comparing data in 2 XMLs

**Source XML:**

```
    <multimap:Messages xmlns:multimap="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
  <multimap:Message1>
    <FSE_BKLOG xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
               xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
               xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
               xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype"
               xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
      <FSE_BKLOGType>
        <FSE_ID>1</FSE_ID>
        <TICKET_TYPE>T</TICKET_TYPE>
        <T_COUNT>259</T_COUNT>
      </FSE_BKLOGType>
      <FSE_BKLOGType>
        <FSE_ID>2</FSE_ID>
        <TICKET_TYPE>T</TICKET_TYPE>
        <T_COUNT>128</T_COUNT>
      </FSE_BKLOGType>
      <FSE_BKLOGType>
        <FSE_ID>3</FSE_ID>
        <TICKET_TYPE>T</TICKET_TYPE>
        <T_COUNT>76</T_COUNT>
      </FSE_BKLOGType>
    </FSE_BKLOG>
  </multimap:Message1>
  <multimap:Message2>
    <FSE_BKLOG>
      <FSE_BKLOGType>
        <FSE_ID>2</FSE_ID>
        <T_COUNT>101</T_COUNT>
        <TICKET_TYPE>T</TICKET_TYPE>
      </FSE_BKLOGType>
      <FSE_BKLOGType>
        <FSE_ID>3</FSE_ID>
        <T_COUNT>101</T_COUNT>
        <TICKET_TYPE>T</TICKET_TYPE>
      </FSE_BKLOGType>
      <FSE_BKLOGType>
        <FSE_ID>4</FSE_ID>
        <T_COUNT>100</T_COUNT>
        <TICKET_TYPE>T</TICKET_TYPE>
      </FSE_BKLOGType>
    </FSE_BKLOG>
  </multimap:Message2>
</multimap:Messages>
```

My requirement is to go inside Message1/FSE_BKLOG/FSE_BKLOGType/FSE_ID and 
compare FSE_ID with the one present inside Message2/FSE_BKLOG/FSE_BKLOGType/FSE_ID
if the value matches then final value xml will have PUT otherwise POST

**Target XML:**

```
<Message>
    <FSE_BKLOGType>
        <Method>POST</Method>
        <FSE_ID>1</FSE_ID>
        <TICKET_TYPE>T</TICKET_TYPE>
        <T_COUNT>259</T_COUNT>
    </FSE_BKLOGType>
    <FSE_BKLOGType>
        <Method>PUT</Method>    
        <FSE_ID>2</FSE_ID>
        <TICKET_TYPE>T</TICKET_TYPE>
        <T_COUNT>128</T_COUNT>
    </FSE_BKLOGType>
    <FSE_BKLOGType>
        <Method>PUT</Method>    
        <FSE_ID>3</FSE_ID>
        <TICKET_TYPE>T</TICKET_TYPE>
        <T_COUNT>76</T_COUNT>
    </FSE_BKLOGType>
</FSE_BKLOG>
</Message>
```

This is what I tried:
this gives me the ones which are common but misses the one which is present in message1.

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ns2:Messages>
      <Message1>
        <FSE_BKLOG>
          <xsl:for-each select="/ns2:Messages/ns2:Message1/FSE_BKLOG/FSE_BKLOGType">
            <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>            
            <xsl:for-each select="/ns2:Messages/ns2:Message2/FSE_BKLOG/FSE_BKLOGType">
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="/ns2:Messages/ns2:Message1/FSE_BKLOG/FSE_BKLOGType[$pos]/FSE_ID = FSE_ID">
                  <FSE_BKLOGType>
                    <METHOD>PUT</METHOD>
                    <FSE_ID>
                      <xsl:value-of select="/ns2:Messages/ns2:Message1/FSE_BKLOG/FSE_BKLOGType[$pos]/FSE_ID"/>
                    </FSE_ID>
                    <T_COUNT>
                      <xsl:value-of select="/ns2:Messages/ns2:Message1/FSE_BKLOG/FSE_BKLOGType[$pos]/T_COUNT"/>
                    </T_COUNT>
                    <TICKET_TYPE>
                      <xsl:value-of select="/ns2:Messages/ns2:Message1/FSE_BKLOG/FSE_BKLOGType[$pos]/TICKET_TYPE"/>
                    </TICKET_TYPE>
                  </FSE_BKLOGType>
                </xsl:when>
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </FSE_BKLOG>
      </Message1>
    </ns2:Messages>
  </xsl:template>
```

Thanks
Yatan

Comment: I have updated with what I tried.

Comment: Please tell us which XSLT processor you will be using (XSLT 1.0 or 2.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key)** to lookup the value from the other branch of the input XML. Here's a simple example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:multimap="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="msg2" match="multimap:Message2/FSE_BKLOG/FSE_BKLOGType" use="FSE_ID" />

<xsl:template match="/multimap:Messages">
    <Message>
        <xsl:for-each select="multimap:Message1/FSE_BKLOG/FSE_BKLOGType">
            <xsl:copy>
                <Method>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="key('msg2', FSE_ID)">PUT</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>POST</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </Method>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Message>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

***Note***: I have not bothered to remove the redundant namespace declarations that are copied to the output, because (a) that's not the point of your question and (b) the exact method depends on the XSLT version you can use (see: [How to mimic copy-namespaces="no" in XSLT 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026224/how-to-mimic-copy-namespaces-no-in-xslt-1-0/9030832#9030832)).