# How to (correctly) use " mode="copy-no-namespaces" "?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having some problems excluding the namespace in my XML output.

By using this template definition and `for-each` in the XSLT I'm creating a sub element in my XML output.

```
<xsl:template match="node()" mode="copy-no-namespaces">
        <xsl:copy >
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

....

<xsl:for-each select="pr:_nested__pl__pl_nc_name/pr:pl__pl_nc_name">
        <plIdentifier_name_literal>
            <xsl:value-of select="pr:pl_nc_name_literal"/>
        </plIdentifier_name_literal>
        <plIdentifier_name_lang>
            <xsl:copy-of select="pr:pl_nc_name_language/pr:generic_lang/pr:_standard"/>
        </plIdentifier_name_lang>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Here a snap of the XML and of the XSLT file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:pr="https://schema.easydb.de/EASYDB/1.0/objects/" exclude-result-prefixes="pr">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="copy-no-namespaces">
        <xsl:copy >
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="pr:objects/pr:pl">
        <entry>
            <plIdentifier_uuid>
                <xsl:value-of select="pr:_uuid"/>
            </plIdentifier_uuid>
            <xsl:for-each select="pr:_nested__pl__pl_nc_name/pr:pl__pl_nc_name">
                <plIdentifier_name_literal>
                    <xsl:value-of select="pr:pl_nc_name_literal"/>
                </plIdentifier_name_literal>
                    <plIdentifier_name_lang>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="pr:pl_nc_name_language/pr:generic_lang/pr:_standard"/>
                    </plIdentifier_name_lang>
            </xsl:for-each>
    
        </entry>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<objects xmlns="https://schema.easydb.de/EASYDB/1.0/objects/" instance="collections" uuid="8ef36ec7-a3a5-4d62-acd5-1ee839f35aa5" base-schema="235" user-schema="212" timestamp="2020-06-29T22:00:21+02:00">
    <pl>
        <_nested__pl__pl_nc_name>
            <pl__pl_nc_name>
                <_id>0</_id>
                <_system_object_id>0</_system_object_id>
                <pl_nc_name_literal type="text_oneline">test</pl_nc_name_literal>
                <pl_nc_name_language>
                    <generic_lang>
                        <_id>5</_id>
                        <_system_object_id>111438</_system_object_id>
                        <_version>2</_version>
                        <_standard>
                            <de-DE>en</de-DE>
                            <en-US>en</en-US>
                            <it-IT>en</it-IT>
                            <fr-FR>en</fr-FR>
                        </_standard>
                        <_objecttype>generic_lang</_objecttype>
                        <_global_object_id>111438@8ef36ec7-a3a5-4d62-acd5-1ee839f35aa5</_global_object_id>
                        <_uuid>0178b42d-0f3f-4132-9e1d-f85425789823</_uuid>
                        <generic_lang_uuid type="string"/>
                        <generic_lang_akronym type="string">en</generic_lang_akronym>
                        <generic_lang_name type="text_l10n_oneline">
                            <de-DE>Englisch</de-DE>
                            <en-US>English</en-US>
                        </generic_lang_name>
                    </generic_lang>
                </pl_nc_name_language>
                <pl_nc_name_source>
                        ....
                </pl_nc_name_source>
            </pl__pl_nc_name>
            <pl__pl_nc_name>
                <_id>0</_id>
                <_system_object_id>0</_system_object_id>
                <pl_nc_name_literal type="text_oneline">test2</pl_nc_name_literal>
                <pl_nc_name_language>
                    <generic_lang>
                        <_id>1</_id>
                        <_system_object_id>111398</_system_object_id>
                        <_version>2</_version>
                        <_standard>
                            <de-DE>de</de-DE>
                            <en-US>de</en-US>
                            <it-IT>de</it-IT>
                            <fr-FR>de</fr-FR>
                        </_standard>
                            ...
                </pl_nc_name_language>
            
            </pl__pl_nc_name>
        </_nested__pl__pl_nc_name>
    </pl>
</objects>
```

It works, however, despite the `mode="copy-no-namespaces"` I'm still having in the output the namespace declaration:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entry>
    <plIdentifier_uuid>ad684334-3ece-4c1d-b2d5-36517356b0c4</plIdentifier_uuid>
    <plIdentifier_name_literal>Test</plIdentifier_name_literal>
    <plIdentifier_name_lang>
        <_standard xmlns="https://schema.easydb.de/EASYDB/1.0/objects/">
            <de-DE>en</de-DE>
            <en-US>en</en-US>
            <it-IT>en</it-IT>
            <fr-FR>en</fr-FR>
        </_standard>
    </plIdentifier_name_lang>
    <plIdentifier_name_literal>test2</plIdentifier_name_literal>
    <plIdentifier_name_lang>
        <_standard xmlns="https://schema.easydb.de/EASYDB/1.0/objects/">
            <de-DE>de</de-DE>
            <en-US>de</en-US>
            <it-IT>de</it-IT>
            <fr-FR>de</fr-FR>
        </_standard>
    </plIdentifier_name_lang>
```

My desired output would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entry>
    <plIdentifier_uuid>ad684334-3ece-4c1d-b2d5-36517356b0c4</plIdentifier_uuid>
    <plIdentifier_name_literal>test</plIdentifier_name_literal>
    <plIdentifier_name_lang>
        
            <de-DE>en</de-DE>
            <en-US>en</en-US>
            <it-IT>en</it-IT>
            <fr-FR>en</fr-FR>
   
    </plIdentifier_name_lang>
    <plIdentifier_name_literal>test2</plIdentifier_name_literal>
    <plIdentifier_name_lang>
      
            <de-DE>de</de-DE>
            <en-US>de</en-US>
            <it-IT>de</it-IT>
            <fr-FR>de</fr-FR>
      
    </plIdentifier_name_lang>
```

For sure the definition of the `mode="copy-no-namespace"` is wrong but then, where I have to declare it?

Comment: It is not clear how your `for-each` relates to the template declared for a certain mode, you will need to show us whether the `for-each` sits in a template of that mode. As for removing namespaces, you will need to show us the input and the desired output to tell what you want to achieve at all. Your code doesn't make any attempts to avoid copying namespaces other than declaring a mode which has that name. You would need to use `xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no"` perhaps, but that only helps for namespaces not needed as part of name of the copied node.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have updated the code

Comment: Just because the mode is called "copy-no-namespaces" doesn't mean it doesn't copy namespaces. In particular, it uses the `xsl:copy` instruction, which DOES copy namespaces.

Comment: `<xsl:copy-of select="pr:pl_nc_name_language/pr:generic_lang/pr:_standard"/>` is copying an element in a namespace to the result, if you don't want that element then don't copy it, transform it or its children with an element that constructs new elements with e.g. `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:element>`.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT has no built-in comprehension of any `mode` value in particular as far as I am aware - these are user-defined, are just names, and just naming a mode according to what you want it to do doesn't make it do that.

The only reference I could find to this name was [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030832/313414) which recursively writes elements using the `local-name()` function and doesn't specify namespaces. xsl:copy *does* copy namespaces, so your problem is nothing to do with the mode invocation, but that the code you are labelling with that mode has the normal behaviour of XSLT, which is to preserve namespaces.