# xsl:copy-of sementics and superfluous namespaces

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Consider this xml.

```
<root xmlns:foo="foo" >
  <foo:a>
    <bar wibble="1"/>
  </foo:a>
</root>
```

and this xslt (here msxsl engine so XSLT 1.0)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    xmlns:foo="foo" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl foo">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <bar>
        <xsl:copy-of select="root/foo:a/bar"/>
      </bar>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which results in this

```
<bar>
  <bar wibble="1" xmlns:foo="foo" />
</bar>
```

now my assumption of this is that the

```
xmlns:foo="foo"
```

is not actually used?
i.e. the above xml is semantically equivalent to

```
<bar>
  <bar wibble="1"/>
</bar>
```

so how do i change the xslt to NOT include it?
(if it doesnt matter then I shouldnt care, but other humans will complain)

Comment: ah is this a duplicate of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026224/how-to-mimic-copy-namespaces-no-in-xslt-1-0
?

Comment: i didnt know about copy-namespaces let me try that

Comment: its a duplicate, i'll close it - it does pose the same question in a more ignorant way though :-)