# xsl:copy-of semantics and superfluous namespaces

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xml-namespaces

I've asked a very similar question which was a duplicate, and this is almost a duplicate of that one EXCEPT the solution to the original question has an issue with it.

This is an irritating question because it revolves around the representation of the the xml, not its meaning - i.e. the problem is that customers will sometimes reject a technically valid program output because it "looks" wrong...even when it isnt.

msxsl (from dotnet core 7)
xslt 1.0

consider this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:kookerella="kookerella.com"
    xmlns:foo="foo.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl foo">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="foo">
         <foo:data>
            <foo:ignore />
            <kookerella:wibble value="1"/>
         </foo:data>
      </xsl:variable>
      <kookerella:root>
         <xsl:copy-of select="msxsl:node-set($foo)/foo:data/kookerella:wibble"/>
      </kookerella:root>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the crux is the namespace "foo" is excluded from the output.

run it (against anything) and we get

```
<kookerella:root xmlns:kookerella="kookerella.com">
  <kookerella:wibble value="1" xmlns:foo="foo.com" />
</kookerella:root>
```

the nasty "foo" is there (perfectly valid - but I did exclude it)...this is the subject of my original question which was a duplicate of another question where the solution is to do this.
[original question/solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026224/how-to-mimic-copy-namespaces-no-in-xslt-1-0)

so this is the solution using that answer:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:kookerella="kookerella.com"
    xmlns:foo="foo.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl foo"
>
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="foo">
         <foo:data>
            <foo:ignore />
            <kookerella:wibble value="1"/>
         </foo:data>
      </xsl:variable>
      <kookerella:root>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($foo)/foo:data/kookerella:wibble" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
      </kookerella:root>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy-no-namespaces">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
         <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="comment()| processing-instruction()" mode="copy-no-namespaces">
      <xsl:copy/>
   </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and we get this:

```
<kookerella:root xmlns:kookerella="kookerella.com">
  <wibble value="1" xmlns="kookerella.com" />
</kookerella:root>
```

correct...its worked...foo is gone, but (I don't know the correct jargon for this) the namespace is now encoded explicitly in the "xmlns" attribute.

how do we get it to use the "kookerella" namespace defined in the root?
(irritatingly) how do we make it 'look' like the original representation but without 'foo'.

Comment: What is the **exact** result you are hoping to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `<xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">` instead of `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">` you might get what you want for that input sample.

Comment: nice! though i dont understand why...maybe its such an edge case scenario i'll suspend non comprehension

Comment: actually ive marked the other answer as the answer, not because there is anything wrong with this one, just that its the same, as was there 1st

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd The answers are not the same and the results are different (I actually hesitated whether to post this answer, but then I decided to follow your lead where you ask explicitly to exclude the prefix on the "copied" element).  As I hinted in my answer, I think the example is too contrived to learn something really useful from it.

Comment: apologies, ive reassigned the answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will solve your real problem - but in the given example, if you want the `xmlns="kookerella.com"`  **default** namespace declaration to appear on the root element, you must put it there yourself, for example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:kookerella="kookerella.com"
xmlns:foo="foo.com"
exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl foo">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="foo">
        <foo:data>
        <foo:ignore />
        <kookerella:wibble value="1"/>
        </foo:data>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <kookerella:root xmlns="kookerella.com">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($foo)/foo:data/kookerella:wibble" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
    </kookerella:root>
</xsl:template>
   
<xsl:template match="*" mode="copy-no-namespaces">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: nice...thanks v much....the nuances of 'local-name()' and 'name()' I'll lookup